# How to make a specific image stop casting reflection?

Tags: mesh, texturing, image

I'm not sure if I explained right in the Title, but what I want is to make the birds stop casting a reflection on the surface of the water (the birds are a image)?
Thanks

[image: v]

Comment: You are really active questioner here, but could I ask you to use question marks "?" at the end of the questions and not exclamation marks "!"? It's just a thing I caught up reading your questions (and answers). Exclamation mark is often used to make a "screaming" statement, and screaming at people from whom you ask help isn't a good idea.

Comment: I know how to use them.. I will be more careful next time